# How to Initialize a Const Structure in C - To Avoid QAC warnings

Tags: c, struct, constants, warnings

I am getting the below QAC warning while initializing a const structure.

```
"[C] Initializer for 'struct', 'union' or array type, or any object with static storage duration, must be a constant "
```

#### FPARM1C2.c

```
 const PROFI_tstBlock FPARM_astFblBlockTable[] = {FPARM_ast_FblBlock_Table};

 const PROFI_tstPartition FPARM_astFblPartitionTable[] = {FPARM_ast_FblPartition_Table};
```

The above declaration causes QAC Warning.

#### FPARM1CA.H

```
#define FPARM_ast_FblBlock_Table \
0x00000000 , 0x00000000 , 0x00000000 , 0x00000000 , 0x00020000 ,  0x00000000 , 0x00001000 , 0x00000000 , FPARM_nMemTypeIntFlash1 , 0x01 ,   0x0000 ,  FPARM_bi8DataBlock | FPARM_bi8CommonBlock , 0x0000

#define FPARM_ast_FblPartition_Table \
(uint32)__ghsbegin_FLoaderIdent, (uint32)0x0, (uint32)FPARM_astFblBlockTable, (uint32) 0x0, 1, 0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
```

#### Profi1c1.h

```
typedef struct PROFI_tstPartition
{
   uint32 xAddressID;           
   uint32 u32Reserved1;
   uint32 xBlockTableAdr;       
   uint32 u32Reserved2;
   uint16 u16NumberOfBlocks;             
   uint16 u16GlobalProperties;           
   uint8  au8Reserved[4];
} PROFI_tstPartition;


typedef struct PROFI_tstBlock
{
    uint32 xPhysicalAddress;             
    uint32 u32Reserved1;
    uint32 xLogicalAddress;              
    uint32 u32Reserved2;
    uint32 xBlockLength;                 
    uint32 u32Reserved3;
    uint32 xSectorSize;                
    uint32 u32Reserved4;
    uint8  u8BlockMemoryType;                  
    uint8  u8Security;                          
    uint16 u16Reserved;                         
    uint16 u16BlockProperties;                   
    uint16 u16Reserved2;                        
} PROFI_tstBlock;
```

Is there any type casting or better way to initialize the const structure to avoid the warnings?

Comment: Initializing an array named `FPARM_astFblPartitionTable` with a value `FPARM_ast_FblPartition_Table` (difference: two underscores) is asking for confusion.  What's `__ghsbegin_FLoaderIdent`? (Note that names beginning with two underscores are reserved for the implementation; that better be from someone else's code.) What's `FPARM_astFblBlockTable`?  It is most probably one of those two that's causing trouble — which you could verify by replacing the values by 0 and seeing that the warning goes away.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion jonathan, but this is a legacy code i inherited and trying to fix the warnings for a software release :)

Comment: The 'change to 0' suggestion is solely to diagnose whether it is one or both of those names that cause the trouble.  Change one to 0; compile.  Change the other to 0; compile.  Without you showing what `txAddressFormat` is, and what `__ghsbegin_FLoaderIdent` and `FPARM_astFblBlockTable` are, we can't help.

Comment: both of these variable cause the warning - i removed both the variable and replace it 0x0- which resolved the QAC warning. Now i should find a way to make the variables const before using it. Thanks again for the suggestion  jonathan

Comment: Should you be using `&__ghsbegin_FLoaderIdent`?  The address would be constant when the value isn't.  Similarly, perhaps, but less confidently, for `FPARM_astFblBlockTable` — that looks like it might be an array.  You've still not given us an MCVE ([MCVE]) which means anyone trying to help is shooting half-blind.

Comment: Try putting your arrays in {}.

Comment: @cup - no that doesnt resolve the warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any variable with static storage duration cannot get initialized from another variable. So if it is an array, it cannot contain any references to other variables in the initializer list.

Don't do something like this:

```
const type1 array1 [] = {1, 2, 3};
const type2 array2 [] = {0, array1, 0}; // won't work
```

Instead do something like this:

```
#define ARRAY1_INIT { 1, 2, 3 }

const type1 array1 [] = ARRAY1_INIT;
const type2 array2 [] = {0, ARRAY1_INIT, 0};
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what is happening in my code, the second Partition array is initialized by Block Array(which is initialized by #define preprocessor directive)